# How to not show chapters in your document but only in your toc

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, appendices

I want to make chapters in my appendix but I dont want them to be in the report itself. I only want them to be in the toc. I also want the "Appendices" to give no page number. Is this possible somehow?

```
\documentclass[11 pt, twoside, openright, tikz]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
{\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage\tableofcontents}
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\chapter{appendix 1}
\chapter{appendix 2}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: The reason behind this is, I have some attachments. But I dont have them in my LaTeX file. So I want to print them individual but still see them in my TOC.

Comment: did you try `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{appendix 1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{appendix 2}`

Comment: Isn't the point of a ToC to itemise the contents of the document? Is it for some kind of practical joke?

Comment: @touhami this did the job

Comment: Check out \includeonly.  It will only show the selectected \includes, but will retain the original chapter and page numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the followinjg once to create the needed aux files.  After uncommenting `\includeonly{chapter2}` it will only show the toc and second chapter, but chapter 2 will start on page 5 as before.

Note: i only used `filecontents` to simplify creating 3 files in one MWE.

```
\begin{filecontents}{chapter1}
\chapter{first}
\end{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{chapter2}
\chapter{second}
\end{filecontents}
%
\documentclass{book}
%\includeonly{chapter2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```